# Fill dictionary property with 2 string properties

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization

So I have 2 properties of type string (Name and Value) and want to puth their values into a Dictionary property, so as a Key Value Pair. Can I do that just in the getter of the dictionary property? They are in the same class.

```
public string TagName { get; set; }

public string TagValue { get; set; }

public Dictionary<string, string> TagNameAndValue {get; set;}
```

Json Output:

```
      {
        "TagName": "processTime",
        "TagValue": "0"
      }
```

But I want it to be this:

```
      {
        "processTime": "0",            
      }
```

I know this might be a different topic, so sorry for that.

Comment: Are you sure you need a `Dictionary`? Looks like you need `KeyValuePair<string, string>`.

Comment: My "teacher" said I could use a Dictionary. The whole thing will be converted to Json with the JsonSerializer, if that changed anything. But say I use KeyValuePair, how would I fill that?

Comment: Considered using `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the properties `TagName` and `TagValue` to initialize dictionary at the declaration.

You can initialize your dictionary with those fields in the constructor like:

```
YourClassConstructor()
{
     TagNameAndValue = new Dictionary<string, string>() { {TagName, TagValue } };
}
```

With C# 6.0 you can assign properties default value, but **you can't use the class fields/properties in property initialization.**

If you would have some constant string values then with C# 6.0 you can do:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> TagNameAndValue { get; set; } = 
                   new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "1", "3" } };
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I tried it in the constructor, but got an Exception, because sometimes the TagValue is null, is there a workaround there? Make it nullable or something?

Comment: Ok nevermind that, checking for null seems to be enough. The output in json is now like described above, so still not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could get what you're after using a library called newtonsoft.json

Type the following in the Package manager console to install the nuget package:

```
install-package newtonsoft.json
```

The dictionary can be parsed using the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` static method. `JsonConvert` resides in the `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("processTime", "25");
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary));
```

You should get an output similar to:

[image]